# Which probability theorem should be applied to these kinds of problems?

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability, poisson-distribution

We are at the semi-final of a football world championship. The countries who have qualified the quarter finals are Sweden, Germany, Mexico and South Korea. In the semi finals Sweden is going to play Mexico and Germany is going to play South Korea. If Sweden wins the match, Germany must win its game to qualify to the finals. If Sweden draws or loses the match, Germany must not lose in order to qualify to the finals. What is the probability that Germany qualifies to the final, given that Sweden loses its match? All possible outcomes of the game are equally likely.

Comment: Probability theorems, and probability theory as a whole, give you the possibility to achieve some implications starting from some assumptions. Both, assumptions and implications, in probabilistic language. If you do not pose any assumptions all implications are possible.

Comment: The short answer is, no particular theorem. Since you say that all outcomes are equally likely, simply enumerating all of them and counting those that match your criteria (Germany qualifies and Sweden loses match) divided by (Sweden loses match) will give you the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability rule here is called the "counting rule" in some textbooks, but others do not name it at all.  In any case, this "rule" says that if you have an event $\mathcal{S}$ composed of possible outcomes that are equally likely, then the probability of any event $\mathcal{E} \subseteq \mathcal{S}$ is:

$$\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E}) = \frac{|\mathcal{E}|}{|\mathcal{S}|}.$$

That is,  if you want to know the probability of one of the outcomes of interest, you just count how many of these outcomes their are and then divide by the number of possible outcomes.  Since all outcomes are equally likely (by assumption) the resulting ratio gives the probability of interest.  (Hat tip to [Tim Mak](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/166238/) for explaining the method in the comments.)